# SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_record', 'wrong version number'

Tags: ssl, proxy

Im running an analytics server that connects to Instgram through the requests library. I'm using proxies and 1 out of 5 of the requests I'm making, I'm getting this error.

I've been looking around the internet and did not find anything that I could understand, any guidance would be much appreciated!

```
IGBOTDriver: Error in my make_request():
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='i.instagram.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded
with url: /api/v1/users/gameaimon/usernameinfo/ 

(Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_record', 
'wrong version number')],)",),))
```

I'm using Ubunto, Apache2 with python 2.7. The script is running on a celery worker in the background.

Comment: Ahoj. Long time ago, still relevant? How was the proxy configured? Would https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50840101/ help?